# Is a full SHA-1 hash overkill for distinguishing javascript file changes?

Tags: hash, cryptography, versioning

I am implementing file versioning on a website using the hash of the individual script files(size of 1 KB-5MB), where the hash is used for cache busting(in query string, for example).

To keep the URLs small, I wanted to truncate the hash to 8 or 10 characters. Are the odds of a collision small enough to use this method, or should I use the full 40 character hash?

Comment: Just do the math:  number of characters in the character-set you are using ^number of characters. For a character set of 64 that would be 64^10 ~= 10^18, one would expect to have a collision around ~10^9 files and you would want a good safety margin.

Comment: Thanks Zaph! I found some resources after putting this question on, and they pointed to the same thing. For 60 bits(if I use base64 10 chars), I don't have to worry about collisions till around 10^8 which is way more than what I expect to hash.

Comment: It's probably computational overkill more than anything.

Comment: Would you recommend another hashing function that is computationally cheaper and would work as well then? I was actually reading some articles that said SHA-512 was cheaper than SHA-256 on 64 bit machines. Not that it would matter, given the low number of ops I'll be doing, but just to satisfy my curiosity :)

Comment: It's faster than SHA-256 (depending on the implementation of course, you can implement SHA-512 using 32 bit word size on a 64 bit machine, SHA-256 may be hardware accelerated etc). But SHA-1 should still trump both wrt speed and will probably be *secure enough* for your use case.

Comment: https://github.com/hollandben/grunt-cache-bust